# AutoMapper don't ignore null properties despite conditions

Tags: c#, automapper

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<ObjectDTO, Object>().ForMember(obj => obj.LastUpdateDate, opt => 
        opt.Condition(pre =>   pre.LastUpdateDate != null));
}

obj.LastUpdateDate = Datetime.Now;
Mapper.map(objDTO,obj);
```

after mapping obj.LastUpdateDate will become null despite the condition  I created.

happens for all members of the object.

Automapper 5.02

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you positive `LastUpdateDate` is `null`? `Datetime` has a default value so if you're not expliciting setting it to `null` your condition won't catch it.

Try:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ObjectDTO, Object>()
       .ForMember(dest => dest.LastUpdateDate, opt => opt.Condition(c => c.LastUpdateDate != null && c.LastUpdateDate != default(DateTime)));
```

Edit:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ObjectDTO, Object>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.Number, opt => opt.Condition(src => src.Number.HasValue))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LastUpdateDate, opt => opt.Condition(src => src.LastUpdateDate.HasValue));

        });

        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var source = new ObjectDTO { LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now };
        var destination = new Object { Number = 10, LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10) };
        var result = Mapper.Map(source, destination);
    }
}

public class ObjectDTO
{
    public int? Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdateDate { get; set; }

}

public class Object
{
    public int? Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastUpdateDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but no, it's a nullable datetime, anyway it doesn't work for any other property

Comment: Ah okay. Can you post a more complete example? Let us see the `Object`and `ObjectDTO` classes and what's in the source and destination objects. It's hard to say without more info but I updated my answer with working example which I think does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is on the *source* object, not on the destination.

So with better naming for variables you are saying:

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.LastUpdateDate, opt => opt.Condition(src => src.LastUpdateDate != null));
```

So, what is in your objDTO?

Comment: Yea I Know the condition is on the source object, that's excatly what I'm trying to do,

Make my DTO merge with my DB Object, and then update the db,
But I don't want to override nulls from the DTO to the DB Object,

DTO is a Data Transfer Object btw,
I used it in the Common Library for all the solution to acknowledge